# Create a row of evenly distributed images (20) in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to create a row of (equal in size) images (20 in total) on one line shown on a desktop and tablet - in two rows when the tablet is tilted or on a mobile device. I've been struggling to find a solution as the framework uses only 12 columns, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read this:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

This is a really good start about how you can create your grid.

I'm sure you will find something that can start you off with the link I have provided.

Thanks